# Is it possible to run android studio in ubuntu 12.04 32 bit system

Tags: android, ubuntu, intellij-idea, android-studio, 32-bit

I'm trying to install Android Studio on 32-bit machine having Intel Dual-Core processor (32-bit) with 4 GB RAM and Intel mobility graphics on Ubuntu 14.04 operating System, but after executing "studio.sh" file I couldn't find any response from Android Setup Wizard nor Android Studio.

Comment: are you having any output in the shell?

Comment: please look into this http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/11/install-android-studio-ubuntu-14-04-ppa/ . It works for my friend

Comment: there is no output  in shell...